# Валидация формы в Laravel 6 (required_without)

Tags: laravel, валидация, laravel5

При валидации, требуется, что бы одно поле из трёх, было обязательно заполнено. Использую данную проверку:

```
'required_without_all:second,third'
'required_without_all:first,third'
'required_without_all:first,second'
```

Дальше пользователь заполняет 1 из этих полей.
Как реализовать дополнительную проверку заполненного поля?

Если я в валидации, после required_without пропишу ещё различные правила проверки, то они будут всегда проверять, а не когда заполнено поле

Comment: 'sometimes|другая валидация'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовал такой способ решения

```
$v->sometimes('first', 'string|min:3|max:20', function ($input) {
    return !empty($input->first);
});
```